# React not reflecting style changes

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, styles

I'm trying to set up a very basic css configuration for my react project. I'm using webpack and style loaders, like so:

```
// webpack.config.js

const {resolve} = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              camelCase: true,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              precision: 8,
              data: "$ENV: " + "PRODUCTION" + ";"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: port
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: resolve("public", "index.html"),
      favicon: resolve("public", "favicon.ico")
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })

  ]
};
```

My problem is that changes in my css file aren't reflected in the html that my react components return.

So if I have a component like:

```
import React from 'react'
require('../../styles/style.scss')

const App = () => (<div className="root">
  <div id='banner1' className='banner'>
    <h1>foo</h1>
    <h2>bar</h2>
  </div>
</div>)

export default App
```

... and an scss file like:

```
#banner1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

... my styles will show up initially, but any changes while the server is still running won't be reflected if I refresh the page. It will only reflect the changes in my stylesheet when I restart the server.

My suspicion is that the `mini-css-extract-plugin` package is minifying the css and packing it into a bundle that react doesn't see in the development environment whenever it's changed, and it doesn't get rebundled.

If I'm right, my conflict is that this is the ubiquitous way I've read in tutorials to set up your webpack configuration, and there is literally zero mention of this side effect being present in a dev environment. Is there an alternate configuration I should be specifying for a dev environment? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: add `hot: true` to `devServer` and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't do anything. Tried adding `--hot` to `webpack-dev-server` too.

Comment: I don't have any experience with `mini-css-extract-plugin` specifically, but it's common for webpack configs to only worry about extracting CSS into separate files on production builds. If you make a separate webpack config for development, you can probably just not use `mini-css-extract-plugin` at all in that one, and let the webpack dev server just serve your CSS through `css-loader`+`style-loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using classname={styles.banner} in case of scss.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).